# Limiting output within a foreach loop

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach, conditional-statements

I have a multidimensional array, called `$alternative`, which contains words.

This array is dynamically generated, sometimes there may only be 3 words, other times there could be 300 words.

In the below code, I am outputting the words from the array to the webpage.

How could I limit the output to say, 10 words?

```
foreach ($alternative as $test)
    {
        foreach ($test as $test2)
        {
        $test3 = ucwords($test2); //Capitalizes first letter of each word
        printf('<li><a href="related.php?query=%1$s" title="%1$s" >%1$s</a></li>', $test3);

        }

    }
```

At the moment, on certain occasions, too many words are being displayed, and I would like to limit it to ten words.

I cannot think of a way to do this. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks guys.

Comment: this code can output 10-300 `<li>` sets, or one `<li>` with 10-300 words in it?

Comment: @Marc B... 10-300 `<li>` sets

Comment: put a counter in side the inner loop, e.g. `if ($count++ > 10) { break; }`

Comment: How is the `$alternative` array made. Just cut of making the array when its larger than 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$counter = 0;
foreach ($alternative as $test) {
    foreach ($test as $test2) {
        $test3 = ucwords($test2); //Capitalizes first letter of each word
        printf('<li><a href="related.php?query=%1$s" title="%1$s" >%1$s</a></li>', $test3);

        if (++$counter > 10) {
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you may put counter inside like :

```
$counter = 0 ;
 foreach ($alternative as $test)
        {
            foreach ($test as $test2)
            {
            $test3 = ucwords($test2); //Capitalizes first letter of each word
            printf('<li><a href="related.php?query=%1$s" title="%1$s" >%1$s</a></li>',       test3);
            if(counter == 9 ) {
            break;
            }else{
               counter++;
            }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Петър Петров, I haven`t the chance to fully test this, The other answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

Simple.  Implement a counter.  The below implementation will spit out 10 `<li>` words for every set of alternative objects.

```
foreach ($alternative as $test)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($test as $test2)
    {
        if ($count >= 10) break;
        $test3 = ucwords($test2); //Capitalizes first letter of each word
        printf('<li><a href="related.php?query=%1$s" title="%1$s" >%1$s</a></li>',$test3);
        $count++;
    }

}
```

For just 10 `<li>` elements total, look at the other answer!

Comment: in this case your counter will be 0 on every upper loop!

Comment: Thanks @Kirk Backus, I haven`t the chance to fully test this, The other answer worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a counter and increment it each time you print a word. Here's a quick example:

```
$max_words = 10;
$nb_words = 0;

foreach ($alternative as $test)
{
    foreach ($test as $test2)
    {
        $test3 = ucwords($test2); //Capitalizes first letter of each word
        printf('<li><a href="related.php?query=%1$s" title="%1$s" >%1$s</a></li>', $test3);
        $nb_words++;

        if($nb_words >= $max_words)
            break;
    }
    if($nb_words >= $max_words)
        break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Y0lk, I haven`t the chance to fully test this, The other answer worked.